# HttpPost keeps catching ClientProtocolException

Tags: android, http-post

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(myURL);
// I can't show my url but it's a verified .asp working both with iOS and browser

try {
    // Add your data                     
    String str = "param1=test&param2=test2&param3=test3";
    StringEntity strEntity = new StringEntity(str, HTTP.UTF_8);
    httppost.setEntity(strEntity);

    httppost.setHeader("Set-Cookie", sessionCookie);
    httppost.setHeader("Accept", "text/html");
    httppost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    httppost.setHeader("Content-Length", strEntity.getContentLength()+""); 

    // Execute HTTP Post Request
    BasicResponseHandler brh = new BasicResponseHandler();
    String responseBody = httpclient.execute(httppost, brh);
    System.out.println(responseBody);
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    // I keep catching this exception
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.err.println("Check network");
}
```

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong but I can't get this working when it's all right in a browser and with my iPhone version of my app.

So any idea? Thanks for your help.

Here is the entire stack trace of the error :

> 11-18 20:31:55.433: W/System.err(1479):
>   org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException 11-18 20:31:55.437:
>   W/System.err(1479):   at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:557)
>   11-18 20:31:55.437: W/System.err(1479):   at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:653)
>   11-18 20:31:55.437: W/System.err(1479):   at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:627)
>   11-18 20:31:55.437: W/System.err(1479):   at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:616)
>   11-18 20:31:55.437: W/System.err(1479):   at
>   com.example.testserverec.MainActivity$SendDataToECTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:97)
>   11-18 20:31:55.437: W/System.err(1479):   at
>   com.example.testserverec.MainActivity$SendDataToECTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
>   11-18 20:31:55.437: W/System.err(1479):   at
>   android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287) 11-18 20:31:55.437:
>   W/System.err(1479):   at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234) 11-18
>   20:31:55.437: W/System.err(1479):     at
>   android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230) 11-18
>   20:31:55.437: W/System.err(1479):     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
>   11-18 20:31:55.437: W/System.err(1479):   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
>   11-18 20:31:55.437: W/System.err(1479):   at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856) 11-18 20:31:55.437:
>   W/System.err(1479): Caused by: org.apache.http.ProtocolException:
>   Content-Length header already present 11-18 20:31:55.437:
>   W/System.err(1479):   at
>   org.apache.http.protocol.RequestContent.process(RequestContent.java:70)
>   11-18 20:31:55.437: W/System.err(1479):   at
>   org.apache.http.protocol.BasicHttpProcessor.process(BasicHttpProcessor.java:290)
>   11-18 20:31:55.437: W/System.err(1479):   at
>   org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.preProcess(HttpRequestExecutor.java:160)
>   11-18 20:31:55.437: W/System.err(1479):   at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:408)
>   11-18 20:31:55.437: W/System.err(1479):   at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
>   11-18 20:31:55.437: W/System.err(1479):   ... 11 more

Comment: Is a message provided with the exception?  If so, what is it?

Comment: @Charles I've edited my post and added the entire stack trace, but you'll see it's not really helpful...

Comment: You don't want the stack trace, you want the message provided by the exception.  It may contain more information on what specifically is going wrong with the HTTP connection.

Comment: Oh finally I found it in the stack trace : `Caused by: org.apache.http.ProtocolException: Content-Length header already present`. I still have an error but this exception isn't catched any longer, my request is correctly send to the server.

Answer (score 0):

So what helped me to solve the problem was this line :

> W/System.err(1479): Caused by: org.apache.http.ProtocolException: Content-Length header already present 11-18 20:31:55.437:

Just had to remove :

```
httppost.setHeader("Content-Length", strEntity.getContentLength()+"");
```

And now I can send my request to the server.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
HttpParams httpParams=new BasicHttpParams();
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(myURL);
// I can't show my url but it's a verified .asp working both with iOS and browser

try {
// Add your data                     
String str = "param1=test&param2=test2&param3=test3";
StringEntity strEntity = new StringEntity(str, HTTP.UTF_8);
httppost.setEntity(strEntity);

httppost.setHeader("Set-Cookie", sessionCookie);
httppost.setHeader("Accept", "text/html");
httppost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
httppost.setHeader("Content-Length", strEntity.getContentLength()+""); 

// Execute HTTP Post Request
BasicResponseHandler brh = new BasicResponseHandler();
String responseBody = httpclient.execute(httppost, brh);
System.out.println(responseBody);
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
// I keep catching this exception
e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
System.err.println("Check network");
}
```

Comment: Tried it, but I still got a ClientProtocolException.